# Why wont this work it makes no sence constructor and super()?

Tags: reactjs, super

```
  49 | export default class Contact extends Component {
  50 |   constructer(props) {
> 51 |     super(props);
     |     ^
  52 | 
  53 |     this.state = {
  54 |       dropdownMan: "dropdownClosed",
```

Failed to compile.

> ./src/components/pages/contact.js Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
> C:/Users/Fastic's win10 pro/Desktop/Whistle
> Coding/apps/Lebaron-Galeana-React-FE/src/components/pages/contact.js:
> super() outside of class constructor (51:4)

Comment: You've spelled `constuctor` as `constructer`

Answer (score -1):

Please check spelling of `constructor`, you have typo there)